# What is this seaplane shown in this photo?

Tags: aircraft-identification, seaplane

While searching I noticed a [seaplane page](https://www.infobloom.com/what-is-a-seaplane.htm) and found a particular seaplane photo that I have never seen before. While the other images showing other seaplanes do have the name, the description of this seaplane image, however, does not show its name. I also couldn't even see the registration on its hull.

So, is this seaplane possibly manufactured by Cessna? If not, then does anybody know what the name is?

[image: Propeller driven seaplane]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a [DHC-2 Beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_DHC-2_Beaver) on floats. The dead giveaway is the unique trapezoid window.